# Override or customize default "longpress mailto:" behavior

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitextview

Currently I'm developing an email app and want all links with mailto scheme to be opened via my app, not default Apple's Mail app.

For instance, I have a link like this one

```
<a href="mailto:email@example.com\>mailto_test</a>
```

in UIWebView or UITextView (doesn't matter which one, they have similar behavior).

When I longpress this link iOS will show UIAlertController with 3 options:

[image]

The first one option, "New Message", will open default Mail app. So my question is how to override this behavior? How can i force this option to launch my own email app?

For those who think it is impossible - take a look at iOS Gmail app. Gmail devs have implemented what I'm asking about, but I don't understand how.

Comment: UIWebView is deprecated. You should be using WKWebView.

Comment: @matt I wonder how does it change anything and how it is related to my question

Comment: did you find out what the answer is? i am really curious about this now

Answer (score 4):

In a text view, link behavior is completely up to you. Give the text view a delegate and implement `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)`. A long press is the `.presentActions` interaction. Return `false` and substitute your own response. You can put up your own `.actionSheet` alert that looks just like the default one, but does what you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

**The solution is to change the default click action of the mail link to the way you want.**

Make a `UITextView` example:

Suppose we have `UITextView` textView, its `attributeString` is

```
<a href="mailto:email@example.com\>mailto_test</a>
```

and its `documentType` is html. The code is below:

```
let textView = UITextView(frame: view.bounds)
textView.frame.origin.y += 100

let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
    data: "<a href=\"mailto:email@example.com\">mailto_test</a>".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
    options:[.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
    documentAttributes: nil)

textView.attributedText = attrStr
view.addSubview(textView)
```

This the default effect that after pressed the `mailto_test` text in the screen the native mail app functions waked up. So we add a `delegate` to the `textView` to modify the click action.

```
textView.isEditable = false
textView.dataDetectorTypes = .link
textView.delegate = self
```

Here is the delegate function to control the specific click action:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    print(URL)
    return false
}
```

Whenever you pressed the mail link, the functions invoked without calling the native mail app. And the URL is just the mail url.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this, right? Where you can open your app from anywhere you click email URL.

[image]

I can't find the exact answer right now, but you want to add your app as a URL Scheme ([Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH1-SW1))

Edit: [more apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/communicating_with_other_apps_using_custom_urls)